# Why doesn't this <input type="checkbox"> have a non-zero width?

Tags: css

I'm scratching my head on this one... I have a generic WooCommerce checkout form being displayed in the attached screenshot. Everything is fine, except for the checkbox to accept the terms & conditions. It has a zero width. In the screenshot, I've applied a border so you can see the field onscreen. It has "visibilty: visible" and "display: inline". I've tried setting width and min-width with no success. This has to be a simple problem staring me right in the face, but for the life of me I'm not seeing the problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what happens when you use `!important`??

Comment: also, give us a way to reproduce the problem so we can help troubleshoot it...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a WP theme, it may have some CSS out of your control? Thinking the theme is hiding default checkboxes to display custom ones. Try searching to see if anything like this exists in your `reset.css`:

```
select, input, textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Note the appearance tags. If so, that means that regular `<input type="checkboxes">` wont display properly. I would override it with one of the classes you have on it, or comment it out.

Something like:

```
.input-checkbox{
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox !important;
    -o-appearance: checkbox !important;
    -ms-appearance: checkbox !important;
    appearance: checkbox !important;
}
```

Comment: @scott8035 - Just checked (based on the URL in your screenshot) and this is the answer.